# How do I calculate Z position of the eye point at lookAt?

Tags: opengl-es, perspectivecamera

I drew a rectangle and bound it with the texture of the image. Then i did some rotation, transition and scale. It works perfectly with orthogonal projection.

Now I'm trying perspective projection.

```
mat4 model = mTranslate(shiftX(), shiftY(), 0.0f)*mRotate(rX, rY, rZ)*mScale(this->kx(), this->ky(), 0.0f);
mat4 MVP = projectionMatr(20.0f * (M_PI / 180), aspect, 0.1f, 10000.0f)*lookAt(0,0,eyeZ,0,0,0,0,1,0)*model;
```

For example, my image equals 200*300 pixels. I want that my rectangle will be not more than 200*300 points on iPad screen. So I need to properly calculate **eyeZ**

How do I calculate **eyeZ**?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little info to go on, but, if you transform your rectangle with the model matrix, take the minimum z-value (of the corners), and call this zmin.
take f to be the cotangent of (20.0f * (M_PI / 180)) / 2. (assuming projectionMatr uses equivalent matrices as gluPerspective)

then if you take eyeZ = max(f + zmin, f/aspect + zmin)

the projection of the closest point of your rectange should be 1:1 (and the rest smaller) and thus the projection will the largest projection smaller or equal to the original rectangle (if measured in the same units).

Comment: The last statement was a little too bold: It's the largest projection where no pixel is projected larger than the original.